# Mac 10.6.8 Zend Server CE MySQL does not start — "ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file"

Tags: mysql, mac, osx-snow-leopard, zend-server-ce

MySQL does not start, I have previously installed zend server on the same Mac and MySQL worked. I have reinstalled after `rm -r /usr/local/zend` .  Are there any other directories I need to clear?
Or do you have any ideas?

/usr/local/zend/mysql/data

```
bash-3.2# echo $PATH
/usr/local/zend/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
bash-3.2# zendctl.sh start-mysql
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
bash-3.2#
```

This is the log file of the failed start-up

```
110817 13:20:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/zend/mysql/data
110817 13:20:09 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
110817 13:20:09 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
110817 13:20:09 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/zend/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
110817 13:20:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
110817 13:20:09 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110817 13:20:09  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
110817 13:20:09  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 0 37356
110817 13:20:09  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 44233
110817 13:20:09  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
110817 13:20:09  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
110817 13:20:09 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
110817 13:20:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/zend/mysql/data/puidhcp-088-227.is.nottingham.ac.uk.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

> [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table
>   'mysql.host' doesn't exist

Run `mysql_install_db` command to initial MySQL data directory and creates the system tables.